# Unicode "not equal" notation in Coq (≠)

Tags: unicode, coq

The following text is mentioned in SF book:

This is how we use not to state that 0 and 1 are different elements of nat:

> ```
> Theorem zero_not_one : ~(0 = 1).
> Proof.
>   intros contra. inversion contra.
> Qed.
> ```
>
> Such inequality statements are frequent enough to warrant a special
>   notation, x ≠ y:
>
> ```
> Check (0 ≠ 1).
> (* ===> Prop *)
> ```

But when I actually do this in Coq:

```
Check (0 ≠ 1).
```

It gives me this error:

```
Syntax Error: Lexer: Undefined token
```

In fact, looking at the [standard
library](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Init.Notations.html), I
cannot seem to find any notation for that. So, what is the proper
notation for it ?

Comment: Not familiar with Coq typed language, but looking at the standard library, surely _not equal to_ would be `<>` or `<->`?

Comment: @JonathonOgden Yeah, you are right. It's `<>`. I looked at that but ignored as it was operation on monoids. :) Can you post that as an answer ?

Comment: Done. Also recommend seeing @Elazar answer. Makes sense.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As @jonathon said, the operator is written `<>`.

```
Check 1 <> 2.
```

But you can also do this:

```
Require Import Unicode.Utf8.
Check 1 ≠ 2.
```

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with Coq typed language, but looking at the standard library, *not equal to* would be written as `<>`.

Comment: `<->` is "If and only if".